# Python 3+ Tkinter Center Label Text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

This is a tkinter question for Python 3+ on Windows OS. So I know how to center Label text `(justify=CENTER)` and I know from everything I've searched for the Label text by default is justified center.

Can someone look at my code below and please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've searched online for hours about this and I just can't see what I'm incorrectly doing.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class MainApplication():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("OOP GUI Example")
        self.master.iconbitmap("Blank.ico")


        label = Label(self.master, text="Test Callback", )
        greet_button = Button(self.master, width=25, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        close_button = Button(self.master, width=25, text="Close", command=self.close)

        Grid.columnconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.master, (0,1,2), weight=1)

        label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSWE",padx=(10, 10), pady=(7.5, 0))
        greet_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSWE", padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 1.5))
        close_button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSWE", padx=(10, 10), pady=(1.5, 10))


    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")
        return


    def close(self):
        self.master.quit()
        return


root = Tk()
root.style = Style()
#  ('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
root.style.theme_use("clam")
gui = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This line here `label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSWE",padx=(10, 10), pady=(7.5, 0))` is making the text left justified. Particularly `sticky="NSWE"` but I want this here so the label widget resizes with the window, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Seems like when a `ttk.Label` is horizontally stretched, using `.pack(fill='x', ...)` or `.grid(sticky='ew', ...)`, it's not getting centered.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the documentation for the tkinter label but you are using a ttk label. This is why you should not use wildcard imports -- when two modules export objects with the same name (eg: `tkinter.Label` and `ttk.Label`) it becomes difficult to know which one is being used in your code. The default for a ttk label is to be aligned left, but the tkinter label is aligned center, and the order of your imports means that you're using a ttk Label.

The quick fix for your example is to explicitly set the `anchor` option for the ttk label (eg: `label.configure(anchor="center")`).

You should also fix your imports so that this problem doesn't happen to you again. Instead of doing a wildcard import (eg: `from tkinter import *`) you should explicitly import the module as a unit, optionally with a shorter name. Once you do that, you need to prefix your widgets with the name of the module.

For example, given these import statements:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

... you would then create a ttk label with `ttk.Label(...)`, and a tkinter label with `tk.Label(...)` which makes your code much easier to understand, and it removes all ambiguity.

Comment: Or you can import ttk as `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a textbook example of namespace clustering. You're clustering python's namespace, with the lines:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

this means if there's a `tkinter.ttk` class that has the same name that of `tkinter` class, `ttk` one will be used, such as `Button` and `Label`. And apparently `ttk` not necessarily have the `tkinter.Label`'s `justify` option. A simple position swap is sufficed to demonstrate the difference swap the imports to:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
```

Instead and see what happens.

---

See below example with center justified text where no namespaces are clustered, using `tkinter.Label` as `label`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Test Callback")
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Text so long that root has to resize.")
btn.pack()
label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

See below example center justified text where no namespaces are clustered, using `tkinter.ttk.Label` as `label`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

label = ttk.Label(root, text="Test Callback")
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Text so long that root has to resize.")
btn.pack()
label.pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ahh I kind of see what you did there but I don't fully understand. Can you please elaborate on why `tk.Label` does not work but `tkk.Label` does work. Why did `tk.Button` and everything else work correctly?

Comment: @jmm5351 I don't understand, doesn't that make your question a simple _"How to justify ttk.Label's text?"_ then? If you want to use clam theme, use ttk version of the widget, if not use the regular. You can have clam themed label on the very last example if needed.

Comment: Does it have to do with import statement having the * and I'm importing everything and the interpreter does not know which one to choose?

Comment: @jmm5351 Yes. Since both `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` has a class named `Label`, the last one overwrites as they're `*`(wildcard) imports. Meaning that it only uses real `tkinter` attributes only when they're not available on `tkinter.ttk`.

Comment: Shouldn't this work then, `import tkinter`, `import tkinter.ttk`, and ` label = tkinter.ttk.Label(self.master, text="Test Callback", )`

I can not seem to get that to work either?

Comment: @jmm5351 Sure, but that would be another question.

Comment: I think it may have to do with the `Grid` since that is a tkinter class and not a tkinter.tkk class.

Comment: @jmm5351 Maybe, gives similar result in the last example above when `fill='both'` is added to label's `pack`.

Answer (score 0):

1rst way:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
```

2nd way:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

With both ways, the first line imports the tk widgets and the second line imports the ttk widgets. The 1rst way is more clear but most tutorials uses the 2nd way.

Example:

```
root = Tk()

button_1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Button 1').pack(padx=20, pady=10)
button_2 = Button(root, text='Button 2').pack(padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

So if you want to use the Button widgets from tkinter.ttk you write `ttk.Button` (like button_1).
If you want to use the Button widget from tkinter (the older one) you just call the `Button` (like button_2).

Answer (score -1):

```
label=Label(root,text="Type your text here...",font="arial 13 bold")
label.place(x=70,y=60,anchor="center")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).